# Count the bytes written to file via BufferedWriter formed by GZIPOutputStream

Tags: java, outputstream, bufferedwriter, gzipoutputstream

I have a `BufferedWriter` as shown below:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        new GZIPOutputStream( hdfs.create(filepath, true ))));

String line = "text";
writer.write(line);
```

I want to find out the bytes written to the file with out querying file like

```
hdfs = FileSystem.get( new URI( "hdfs://localhost:8020" ), configuration );

filepath = new Path("path");
hdfs.getFileStatus(filepath).getLen();
```

as it will add overhead and I don't want that.

Also I cant do this:

```
line.getBytes().length;
```

As it give size before compression.

Comment: Sounds like you want some kind of Java [`tee`](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/need-to-write-same-content-to-multiple.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [CountingOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/CountingOutputStream.html) from Apache commons IO library.

Place it between the GZIPOutputStream and the file Outputstream (hdfs.create(..)).

After writing the content to the file you can read the number of written bytes from the CountingOutputStream instance.

Answer (score 2):

If this isn't too late and you are using 1.7+ and you don't wan't to pull in an entire library like [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) or [Commons-IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/), you can just extend the [GZIPOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) and obtain the data from the associated [Deflater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) like so:

```
public class MyGZIPOutputStream extends GZIPOutputStream {

  public MyGZIPOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
      super(out);
  }

  public long getBytesRead() {
      return def.getBytesRead();
  }

  public long getBytesWritten() {
      return def.getBytesWritten();
  }

  public void setLevel(int level) {
      def.setLevel(level);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make you own descendant of `OutputStream` and count how many time `write` method was invoked

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the response by Olaseni, but I moved the counting into the `BufferedOutputStream` rather than the `GZIPOutputStream`, and this is more robust, since `def.getBytesRead()` in Olaseni's answer is not available after the stream has been closed.

With the implementation below, you can supply your own `AtomicLong` to the constructor so that you can assign the `CountingBufferedOutputStream` in a try-with-resources block, but still retrieve the count after the block has exited (i.e. after the file is closed).

```
public static class CountingBufferedOutputStream extends BufferedOutputStream {
    private final AtomicLong bytesWritten;

    public CountingBufferedOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        super(out);
        this.bytesWritten = new AtomicLong();
    }

    public CountingBufferedOutputStream(OutputStream out, int bufSize) throws IOException {
        super(out, bufSize);
        this.bytesWritten = new AtomicLong();
    }

    public CountingBufferedOutputStream(OutputStream out, int bufSize, AtomicLong bytesWritten)
            throws IOException {
        super(out, bufSize);
        this.bytesWritten = bytesWritten;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        super.write(b);
        bytesWritten.addAndGet(b.length);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        super.write(b, off, len);
        bytesWritten.addAndGet(len);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void write(int b) throws IOException {
        super.write(b);
        bytesWritten.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public long getBytesWritten() {
        return bytesWritten.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if we can hit an issue with duplicated counting, let's say some inner implementation would call write like that: write(byte[] b, int off, int len) followed by write(int b) for every byte in the array. We run into the issue with those bytes counted twice.

Comment: @kolboc no, the write(byte[] b, int off, int len) call in that case would not be in the loop with the write(int b) call, so there world be no double counting.

Comment: For this specific implementation, it might be safe, but generally, it's a possibility. That might be a good reason to write such counting streams as wrappers instead, and instead of super calls, use the instance of the wrapped stream. 
eg. class CountintOutputStream(val outputStream: OutputStream): OutputStream {
  override write(int b) { byteCount++; outputStream.write(b); }
}
That way you're safe to do that regardless of things going on under the hood.

Comment: Sorry, there is simply no way for this to count bytes wrongly. The implementation I gave counts exactly the number of bytes written. There is no way to call this and have a different number of bytes written than is counted. The implementation you showed is pretty much exactly my `write(int)` method.